# Area 51 has a proposal cousin to Poker SE

Tags: discussion

[Casinos & Gambling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103468/casinos-gambling) has been proposed for Stack Exchange, and is for

> gamblers, casino and industry professionals, and those interested in aspects of the games, workplaces, etiquette, standards and life of the casino and gambling industries.

As a number of Poker SE users are also involved with the casino and gambling industries, and poker itself is a related topic, I believe many will be interested in supporting this proposal.

**But we've already tried that...**

Casino Gaming SE was proposed and closed some years ago, that's true. This proposal is wider in scope - it includes all forms of gambling, and all aspects of the industries and people and places related to casinos and gambling. This ensures it can be broad enough to be viable on Stack Exchange while focused enough to grow into its niche.

**We don't want Poker SE to be clumped with this!**

Good! It should not be. Poker SE is a thriving community dealing with a subject that would not always be on-topic in an area dealing with casinos and gambling. It wasn't merged with Sports SE or Board & Card Games SE or even Mathematics SE, despite most of the questions fitting somehow in one of those areas.

I think the same will currently apply to Casinos & Gambling, though of course, I make no promises for what the communities themselves decide in the future.

**So, if you believe this proposal would complement Poker SE, or simply approve on its own merits, please commit and suggest new questions now.**

Comment: Have you looked at the stats for Poker on Area 51? It's not what I would call a "thriving" community. This is also evidenced by the lack of discussion on the pro-tem mod on meta as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the proposal mentioned in this question didn't make it, but there is a [Gambling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104823/gambling) proposal which is now at the definition phase if anyone is interested in following it (as I am).

Comment: (Note: the Gambling proposal also didn't make it.)

Answer (score 0):

Why is this a cousin site for Poker but not for Chess? Poker has nothing to do with gambling! I wouldn't say we are a thriving community either, given that we're still on Beta and not that many relevant questions are asked anyway

Comment: Poker is gambling by definition in a vast number of countries, and is culturally associated with it at least in the anglophone world.

Comment: @Nij so is astrology to astronomy but that doesn't make it a science

Comment: Astrology is not astronomy by definition, nor is it culturally associated except by the very tangential fact that they involve looking at stars. What a nonsense comment to make after two years.